# What To Learn First If I Want To Build A Web Application?

Tags: web-applications

What should I learn first if I want to build a web application? I just had an excellent idea that I want to work on for a few years myself. I don't have any experience programming besides doing HTML and some bits of CSS. I'm a novice in using the command line (Terminal) in Linux but I have been trying to improve myself on that part.

Comment: If it's an excellent idea, get some capital and hire someone to do it now. It might not be such an excellent idea in 'a few years' once you're done!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to learn a bit about a language for web application design.

The simplest thing would be the LAMP stack: Linux, Apache, PHP, and MySQL.

If you're a Windows junkie you'll probably want .NET.

Or you could write the back end in Java.

The point is that HTML and CSS are vital for the client, but now you'll have to be taking care of the back end as well.

Here's a list of things you'll want to know more about:

JavaScript, jQuery, HTTP, networking, relational databases, and SQL.

Start with those.

Comment: Thanks. If you don't mind, could I ask something else too? Would Ruby And Rails be useful for me to learn? Bad idea to learn this right now as a beginner, or wouldn't be useful even if I became better in the future?

Comment: Sure, Ruby on Rails won't be a bad thing to learn.  I don't see it making much of a dent in the marketplace, but then I work at one of those large, conservative corporations that are fearful of new technologies.

Answer (score 2):

Try to learn PHP. It's a good web development language, and pretty easy to learn and use. Find a PHP tutorial on Google and use www.php.net heavily.

You should also learn SQL, because you probably want to store and retrieve stuff from a database. MySQL is pretty easy to install and use.

Good luck.